# Moving Vobs between Win and AIX

Tags: clearcase-ucm, server-administration

Prior to upgrading UCM from 7.1.2.6 to 8.x we need to amalgamate the vobs on a windows server to a common vob sever on aix.

However it appears we have a bit of a Siamese twin set up that from the Windows Region I can already see both sets of VOBS.

When checking, The existing vobs on AIX and Windows share a common ADMIN PVOB (aix).
In Project Explorer Both sets of vobs share a common PVOB and both sets of components are visible together.

I am therefore wondering to move the VOBS (`.vbs`) from windows to AIX server should I be able to move the `vbs` across to aix then when I do the various reformats and protects and re do the hyperlink to the admin vob that it should all knit back together?

Comment: Hi Sorry, been dumped in a pile of whatever juggling a couple of different threads. Have now updated. Thanks for the reminder of the house rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The existing vobs on AIX and Windows share a common ADMIN PVOB (aix)

That means after dumping ([`db_dumper/db_loader`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21172574)) and/or [reformatting the Vob](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_reformatvob.htm) from Windows to Aix, you should not have to "re do the hyperlink to the admin vob": they should already be there, in the new (moved) Vob.

Comment: Hi, We have moved the dumped vbs from Windows to AIX run the fix_prot on the new server. But now when we run the reformatvob -load it goes through it's steps Shows "Loader Done" then shows the following errors - Error from vob database /vobstore/vobs/vobname.vbs. Error Trouble Opening the VOB Database /vobstore/vobs/vobname.vbs, Error Trouble Loading versioned object base /vobstore/vobs/vobname.vbs. Becasue of the shared nature of this setup These vobs show in the Clearcase Registry as old server, therefore is this due to shared regisrty and we need to unreg and then rmtag,

Comment: @DBeange That is best addressed as a new question (with a link back to this one for context), and check if the vob server logs shows anything.