# Reformat Load fails in Clearcase 7.1.26

Tags: clearcase

This is a follow on from op - [Moving Vobs between Win and AIX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45372627/6788057)
Due to the aix and win vob servers sharing resources (common CC reg & Common Admin PVOB on the Aix box) we need to amalgamate these vob servers onto the AIX server as a precursor to our ultimate move to new servers at CC8.

on the Win VOb Server we have locked the vob, run vob_siddump then a reformat dump of the vob. 
Then using xcopy we copied the dumped vob.vbs from Windows to AIX vob server run the `fix_prot` on the new server.
But when we run the reformatvob -load it goes through it's steps Shows "`Loader Done`" then shows the following errors

```
Error from vob database /vobstore/vobs/vobname.vbs. 
Error Trouble Opening the VOB Database /vobstore/vobs/vobname.vbs, 
Error Trouble Loading versioned object base /vobstore/vobs/vobname.vbs.
```

Because of the shared registry is this due to the existing registry entry and we need to unregister and then `rmtag` before registering and tagging fresh or do we need to do anything further?

Clearcase logs on aix vob server show:

```
DB Log - Error process not running on registery specified hostname (old win vob server)
Vob Log - shows unix UID and GID messange and Warning unable to verify mount options in vob tag registry Clearcase Object not found
```

Comment: load in 7.1.26? I though you were moving from CC7 to CC8?

Comment: Yes ultimately moving from CC7 to CC8 but this is a precursor amalgamating 2 existing vob severs on to single existing aix CC7 as first steps to migration

Comment: OK, you can edit your question to add/detail/epxlain that step: I missed it completely.

Comment: So you have Aix servers in CC7, and target Aix server in CC8?

Comment: This activity is taking cc7 vobs from windows to amalgamate with other existing cc7 vobs on aix as both vob servers currently share the same cc registry on aix and the same admin pvob on aix. So this amalgamation is to have one common vob server in prep for moving to new CC8 aix server.

Comment: OK. Got it. Now, by "amalgamate", do you mean you have two vobs with different content that you want to merge into one content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David, there are a few things you need to do here:

1. unregister the VOB and remove all the tags that refer to the old server
2. reregister and retag the vobs at the new location.
3. If you can't register the VOB, run fix_prot -r -root ... to reset the ownership and try again.
4. run vob_sidwalk to remap object ownership.
5. run it again with -recover_filesystem to reset container ownership. Alternatively run checkvob -pool -protections -fix -force {vob storage dir}.

The last step really needed to be started on the Windows side before this started. Essentially, you needed a sid dump file to turn into the map file that the sidwalk needs (unless you want to remap everything to the VOB owner...)

The complete procedure to follow is at [Moving VOBs between Operating system types](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_mvvob_2os.htm) You may want to start fresh from there if you still have the VOB located in the old location.

Comment: Thanks Brian, In the end I missed removing the tags for the original server before dumping and moving so had to remove them via admin console later.

Did the reformatvob -load register & mktag for the vob on new server

Amended the sid_walk file
sid_walk to remap ownership
sid_walk recover_filesystem

regiion sync & Apply Triggers.

The hyperlinks to the admin vob were okay as as had already been pointing to the Admin vob on the target